# How to fix the error that shows me vagrant when executing the vagrant up command?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm following this tutorial **https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-create-a-vagrant-base-box-from-an-existing-one** to create my own box with vagrant, I follow everything to the letter and came to the end, but at the time of executing the command:
**vagrant up**

Begins to repeatedly display the message of: **Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...**

Until he finishes trying and takes me out

How can I solve it?

Thank you!

greetings

Answer (score 0):

When you do the first `vagrant up` vagrant is expecting to find the [vagrant insecure key](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys) ax the vagrant user SSH key, so it can ssh to the VM the first time. Vagrant then replace the key with a newly generated one.

The tutorial you use failed to mention that I think.

After you customized your machine, when you executed the `vagrant package` command, the insecure key was already replaced. After that vagrant could no longer connect to any VM generated from that custom box, hence the **Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...** message.

So as the last customisation operation before packaging, you always need to put back the insecure key.